converting type to unsafe pointer and back in golang
i expect this code:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type Foo struct {
    inc int
}

func newFoo() any {
    return Foo{inc: 10}
}

func main() {
    v := newFoo()
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", v)
    rptr := &v
    ptr := unsafe.Pointer(rptr)
    vv := (*Foo)(ptr)
    fmt.Println(vv)
}

to print:{10} &{10}
but why does it unexpectedly print:{10} &{4846816}
i even tried to pass the v itself but pointer doesn't accept any type

Your newFoo function returns an any value, which is what you attempted to convert to *Foo

any is not a magical "any type", it is the any type.

Let's break this down a little:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type Foo struct {
    inc int
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{inc: 10}

    v := any(foo)
    foo.inc += 10

    fmt.Printf("foo=%+v, v=%+v\n", foo, v)

    var rptr *any = &v

    fmt.Printf("rptr type is %T\n", rptr)

    foo = Foo{inc: 25}
    *rptr = any(Foo{inc: 15})

    fmt.Printf("foo=%+v, v=%+v\n", foo, v)

    ptr := unsafe.Pointer(rptr)
    vv := (*Foo)(ptr) // ❌ invalid reinterpretation of private memory layout

    fmt.Println(vv)
}

The first fmt.Printf prints “foo={inc:20}, v={inc:10}”, so you see that you actually got a copy of foo, wrapped in an interface.
Then you take the address of the interface variable, resulting in a (pointer) variable of type *any.
When you modify foo and *rptr, the latter pointing to v, you see the (independent) results in the third fmt.Printf, giving “foo={inc:25}, v={inc:15}”.
Lastly, you convert a pointer to an interface (with a private memory layout) into an pointer to a Foo structure, which is invalid.
The main takeaway might be that any (which is an alias for interface{}) is a different type than Foo.
